# Consumer only accepts Model from same application

Tags: .net, azureservicebus, masstransit

I think im getting something wrong with how MassTransit should work. Im running a WebAPI with a Consumer

```
  public class DoSomethingConsumer :
        IConsumer<DoSomething>
    {




 public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<DoSomething> context)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(context.Message.Value);
        await context.RespondAsync<DoSomething>(new
        {

            Value = $"Received: {context.Message.Value}"
        });
    }
```

}

And a Console APP where im publishing DoSomething events

```
 TaskUtil.Await(() => bus.Publish(new DoSomething {Value = "33"}));
            TaskUtil.Await(() => bus.Publish(new DoSomething {Value = "11"}));
```

But my consumer on the webAPI doesnt detect the DoSomethings...only if i publish them from my webApi, the contract is the same, but it wont work, what im missing here?

Comment: Probably a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57706224/cant-reach-consumer -- short answer, namespaces must be the same.

Comment: Issues with messages aren't being received are _always_ in the configuration or invalid topology. When configured properly, like it is described in the docs, MassTransit _always_ works. Besides, what's the point responding if you don't use request-response?

Comment: Thanks @ChrisPatterson